# Current Starved inverter with current sources connected to Vout node

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, delay

The `figure a` is the conventional Current Starved inverter with `M1` and `M2` acting as current sources.

However, I saw somewhere the variant as `figure b`. The current sources are now connected to the `Vout` node instead. 
What is the advantage of the structure in `figure b`?

**UPADE FIGURE:**

[image]

Comment: M1 and M2 don't have any bias at all, in either diagram - are the schematics complete?

Comment: M1 and M2 are biased by M5 and M6 but they're missing the mirror structure. I think you're right. 
I copied it somewhere and make some editing but assume that they're biased properly by M5, M6 via mirror structure.

Answer (score 1):

In diagram 'b' I would expect M3 and M4 to have higher gain from Vin to Vout and less Miller feedback as they are separated from the output by M1 and M2.

This lower feedback will also result in less capacitance loading on the previous stage giving a faster transition time. Possibly less energy consumption per transition (lower power consumption when cycling).

The voltage levels will be almost identical.

Comment: In figure b transistor M3 and M4 should turn on first for M1 and M2 becoming current sources. Is there any problem with this?

Comment: @anhnha - not that I can think of.